# Python: what does d = _ mean?

Tags: python

At 44:05 in his [Fun of Reinvention](https://youtu.be/js_0wjzuMfc?t=2648) talk, Dave Beasley writes

```
>>> d = _
```

There is a lot before that, which is necessary for the result he gets. But ignoring the output, what does that input line mean? Whenever I try it, either in a file in the PyCharm editor, in the PyCharm Python console, using straight IDLE (all v3.7) I get an error.

Any idea what this may mean and how to get something like that to run?

Thanks

Comment: Did you make sure to run the stuff before that first? You can't just execute one line out of context and expect it to work.

Comment: Yes, I ran all the stuff before that. But I ran it in a file, not line-by-line in IDLE. The result is different! Thanks to the link above and the answer below, I now see it's a special symbol in a REPL like IDLE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_` is a special variable in the python language.

In some REPLs, like IDLE, it holds the result of the last expression executed.

`d = _` assigns the result of the last expression executed to `d`.

Comment: This is *only true in a repl*. It has no special status other than that, and other interactive repls (IPython) have other such "special" variables.

Comment: I've edited in a clarification. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the IDLE use to refer to the previous result. I tried it in a file with all the previous stuff, but in that context, it doesn't mean the same thing!